# How do I fix this unintentional chromatic aberration on a lightmap?

Tags: graphics, color, lightmap

Some strange rainbow halos (front and left) appear after computation of a lightmap for direct light. The formula is

```
dot * dot2 / ( dist * dist ) * dl->intensity
```

with gamma correction, lightmap is computed as `vec3_t` and ultimately cropped to 3 bytes. However, brightness of the region in question fit into 255 nicely, and even calculating in byte instead of float beforehand - result in just a subtle "oil painting" effect and does not produce such artifact across entire image.

My best guess is how this artifact appear from base change in a floating point math, but I don't know for sure nor do I understand what exactly is happening.

[image: artifact]

Comment: What format do you save your lightmap in? Do you use any compression? [You might need to apply some dithering to break up the quantization banding, as described in this talk](https://gdcvault.com/play/1023304/Low-Complexity-High-Fidelity-INSIDE)

Comment: RGB24, no compression.

Comment: Is dl->intensity a shade of grey or else what is it?

Comment: Are you sure it is texture itself where problem resides? Maybe it is caused by some post processes? Does texture have this problem when viewed in external viewer?

Comment: @Sergio Good thinking, I opened map in Crafty, and apparently it is an effect from a gamma correction applied by the game engine.

Comment: @user253751 it's rgb(254 216 146) * (150/255)

Comment: @ivan-feoktistov then it might be a problem with gamma/linear space conversion. I don't know if it is your own engine or some widely available, but here is reference for Unity that explains the topic https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LinearRendering-LinearOrGammaWorkflow.html